# Границы кириллических слов в регулярных выражениях JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть простенькая регулярка:

```
var regex = /\bмыла\b/;
```

Вроде все просто - она должна находить слово "мыла", ограниченное не словесными символами. Но вот эта строка возвращает false:

```
regex.test('Мама мыла раму');
```

Тогда как вот такая регулярка возвращает true:

```
var regex = /мыла/;
regex.test('Мама мыла раму'); // true
```

Но и это ещё не всё. Вот в этом случае всё работает:

```
var regex = /\bsun\b/;
regex.test('The sun is bright'); // true
```

Разница только в том, что в первом случае кириллические символы, а во втором латинские.

Но и это ещё не всё. В [этом сервисе](https://regex101.com/r/iJ7sJ9/1) пример не работает. А [вот в этом](http://regexstorm.net/tester) работает.

Comment: строго говоря во втором сервисе .net регулярки, а в первом в зависимости от настроек может быть js, pcre, python. Данные проверки не значительно, но отличаются

Comment: `\b` в JavaScript работает только с латинницей.

Comment: действительно :-) и [ссылочка на стандарт](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.6)

Comment: А теперь, что делать. `XRegExp` можете использовать? Хотя, самое простое, проверять на наличие пробелов. `var regex = /(?:^|\s)мыла(?!\S)/;`. Ну, или `var regex = /(?:^|[^а-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_])мыла(?![а-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_])/;`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561756/%d0%a1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Снова регулярки в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561756/%d0%a1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew что-то я не понял, почему дубликат?

Comment: @andreymal По-моему, [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561771/182013) поможет решить данную проблему.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ответ может и похож, но вопросы-то вроде разные

Comment: Кстати, `\bмыла\b` работает на RegexStorm.net, так как этот сайт поддерживает синтаксис регулярных выражений .NET, там `\b` поддерживают Юникод. А [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iJ7sJ9/2) тоже надо знать, как использовать. Для тестрирования регулярок JS надо выбрать соответствующую опцию.

Answer (score 3):

Это дискриминация по языку :)

`\b` это граница слова.

> При поиске движок регулярных выражений идёт по шаблону и одновременно по строке, пытаясь построить соответствие. Когда он видит \b, то проверяет, что текущая позиция в строке подходит под одно из условий:
>
> - Начало текста, если первый символ \w.
> - Конец текста, если последний символ \w.
> - Внутри текста, если с одной стороны \w, а с другой – не \w.

А что такое `\w` в *javascript*?

> \w (от английского «word» – «слово»)
>
> Символ «слова», а точнее – буква латинского алфавита или цифра или подчёркивание '_'. **Не-английские буквы не являются \w, то есть русская буква не подходит.**

Источник https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-character-classes

Comment: Не по языку совсем, только по "скрипту", т.е. набору символов. Латинница используется во многих языках.

Comment: Одновременно с вами стали искать причину в word boundary. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, в php если я использую модификатор Юникода, \w будет соответствовать не только латинским символам, цифрам и подчеркиванию. Идея тут в этом.

Comment: Само понимание, как ведет себя `\b` делу не поможет.

Comment: Это все хорошо, но как мне быть-то?

Comment: @Pupkin, смотреть ответ @VenZell, там по ссылке в ответе есть вариант `

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, что значит не поможет? Я написал причину того, почему в js \b не срабатывает с русскими буквами. Что не так?

Comment: Это  только объяснение, но не решение.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а вы мне покажите в вопросе, где автор просит составить регулярку , которая будет работать с русскими буквами? Автор всего лишь в недоумении, почему так не работает, а эдак работает. Вот и все.

Comment: [*Это все хорошо, но как мне быть-то?*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560989/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-js/560993?noredirect=1#comment729295_560993) Кстати, минус не мой. Всё-таки, верное объяснение.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, пусть автор вопроса изменит смысл вопроса и вы ответите на его вопрос правильно.

Answer (score 2):

[@Visman привёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560993/182013) верное определение границы слова в своём ответе, `\w` = `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (буква из набора ASCII, цифра от 0 до 9 или знак нижнего подчёркивания), `\W` = `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` (любой символ кроме буквы из набора ASCII, цифры от 0 до 9 и знака нижнего подчёркивания), поэтому для `\b` и `м`, и `?` являются `\W`.

Я предлагаю два решения, основанные на стандарте ECMAScript 2018 и более современных (см. [аналогичные решения на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66680311/3832970)).

#### Решение 1

1. Шаблон левой (начальной) границы слова можно определить как *позицию, сразу перед которой нет буквы (сразу после которой может быть ноль и более диакритических знаков), цифра или знак нижнего подчёркивания*: `(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])`
2. Шаблон правой (конечной) границы слова можно определить как *позицию, сразу после которой нет буквы, цифры или знака нижнего подчёркивания*: `(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])`.

Пример использования:

```js
var regex = /(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])мыла(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])/u;
console.log(regex.test('Мама мыла раму')); // => true
console.log(regex.test('Мама помыла раму')); // => false

// Создание шаблона с помощью переменной
var slovo = 'мыла';
var regex2 = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])${slovo}(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])`, 'u');
console.log(regex2.test('Мама мыла раму')); // => true
console.log(regex2.test('Мама помыла раму')); // => false
```

#### Решение 2

Так как шаблон [`\w` в режиме полной поддержки Юникода эквивалентен](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772689/3832970) `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`, мы можем определить `\b` как `(?:(?<=^)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=$)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W))`:

```js
const w = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const nw = String.raw`[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const uwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=^)(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=$)|(?<=${nw})(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=${nw}))`;
console.log(uwb);
```

Решение будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
const w = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const nw = String.raw`[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const uwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=^)(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=$)|(?<=${nw})(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=${nw}))`;

var slovo = 'мыла';
var regex = new RegExp(`${uwb}${slovo}${uwb}`, 'u');
console.log(regex.test('Мама мыла раму')); // => true
console.log(regex.test('Мама помыла раму')); // => false
```

**Использование флага `u` обязательно**, он обеспечивает поддержку символьных классов Юникода ("Unicode category (property) classes") в шаблонах, совместимых со стандартом ECMAScript 2018+.

Answer (score 0):

Совпадение по границе слов работает только в том случае, если слову не предшествует или за словом не следует символ из набора `\w`, а если точнее, то: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Поскольку кириллица не входит в набор `\w`, `\b` использовать с кириллицей нельзя, он не определит границу слова.

На основе ответа: [utf-8 word boundary regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2881472/2486051).