# Снова регулярки в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день! У меня есть регулярка такого вида:

```
/((^|[\s\.\,\;])(text)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(textf)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(texts)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(textt)($|[\s\.\,\;]))/gi
```

Она состоит из почти одинаковых блоков вида `(^|[\s\.\,\;])(text)($|[\s\.\,\;])`

которые различаются только формами искомого слова. Регулярка ищет все вхождения слова text в различных вариациях (text, textf, texts, textt).

Вот как я ее использую:

```
'textf  some words texts another words. Textt bla-bla-bla'.replace(/((^|[\s\.\,\;])(textf)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(texts)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(textt)($|[\s\.\,\;]))/gi,
function() {
    console.log('"' + arguments[0] + '"');
    return '<a>' + arguments[0] + '</a>';    
})
```

`console.log(arguments[90])`

выводит вот это:

"textf "
" texts "
" Textt "

Сама же строка после замены выглядит так:

```
<a>textf </a> some words<a> texts </a>another words.<a> Textt </a>bla-bla-bla
```

То есть как можно видеть совпадения, найденные регуляркой, включают в себя и пробелы с запятыми, которые по идее должны быть границами слов и не участвовать в замене. Очевидно я как-то неправильно составил регулярку. Хотелось бы чтобы текст в итоге был таким:

```
<a>textf</a> some words<a>texts</a> another words.<a>Textt</a> bla-bla-bla
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне изменить регулярку чтобы добиться этого?

Comment: Зачем регулярка такая сложная? Можно же было написать `/(^ | [\s\.\,\;]) (text | textf | texts | textt) ($ | [\s\.\,\;])/gi`

Comment: Можно было еще проще, если слова состоят из латинских символов: `\b(?:textf|texts|textt)\b`

Comment: @PavelMayorov регулярку делаю не я. Я скармливаю некий текст библиотеке, а она мне выдает регулярку по нему.

Comment: @Visman текст кириллический, поэтому \b не подходит

Comment: @Pupkin в таком случае проблема - в библиотеке.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо конечно, но это я и сам понимаю

Comment: @Pupkin но зачем вы просите *"Подскажите пожалуйста как мне изменить регулярку чтобы добиться этого?"* - если регулярку дает библиотека и вы не можете ее менять?

Comment: @PavelMayorov теоретически я могу ее менять конечно. Просто если менять ее кардинально, то это едва ли проще чем писать новые регулярки самому. Я думал, может есть какое-то решение, позволяющее обойтись малой кровью

Comment: @Pupkin в настолько сложной регулярке малой кровью не обойтись никак.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну я имел в виду, можнт, я как-то не так расставил скобки группировки или что-то в этом роде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в регулярке, а в том, что используется для подставления.

Если обратиться к справке по функции *replace*, можно увидеть какие параметры принимает функция передаваемая вторым аргументом

1. *match* - часть строки удовлетворяющая регулярному выражению
2. *p1, p2, ...* - значения конкретных групп, указанных в регулярном выражении. Количество этих параметров соответствует количеству групп.
3. *offset* - смещение части строки удовлетворяющей регулярному выражению
4. *string* - Вся рассматриваемая строка.

Так как используется множество групп, подставлять нужно конкретную

```js
var result = 'textf  some words texts another words. Textt bla-bla-bla'.replace(/((^|[\s\.\,\;])(textf)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(texts)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(textt)($|[\s\.\,\;]))/gi,
  function(...[, , , $1, , , $2, , , $3]) { // представим, что аргументы переданы в массиве и возьмем элементы с индексами 3,6,9
    return '<a>' + ($1 || $2 || $3) + '</a>';
  });

console.log('result:', result);
```

Подробнее про конструкции в коде можно узнать тут:

- [rest-параметры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Или так:

```js
var result = 'textf  some words texts another words. Textt bla-bla-bla'.replace(/((^|[\s\.\,\;])(textf)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(texts)($|[\s\.\,\;])|(^|[\s\.\,\;])(textt)($|[\s\.\,\;]))/gi,
  function() { // представим, что аргументы переданы в массиве и возьмем элементы с индексами 3,6,9
    return '<a>' + (arguments[3] || arguments[6] || arguments[9]) + '</a>';
  });

console.log('result:', result);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но я к сожалению не понял, как это работает. Точнее, что за многоточие и куча запятых в аргументах функции?

Comment: @Pupkin, это просто более компактная форма.

Comment: @Pupkin, добавил описание параметров в ответ.

Comment: @Grundy, у вас скрипт прямо тут выдает ошибку.

Comment: @Visman, зависит от браузера. _rest-параметры_ и _destructuring assignment_ еще не везде имплементированы. Точно не будет работать в IE

Comment: @Grundy, зачем мне в IE, если он даже в FF 47 не работает!?

Comment: @Visman, я же не сказал, что _только_ в IE не работает.

Comment: @Grundy, ну и я просто проинформировал, что у 50% посетителей сайта данное решение может не работать.

Comment: @Visman, это просто пример решения. Он не обязан работать у всех. Суть ответа как раз в том, что данные не от туда берутся и добавлен пример как это можно сделать в браузере поддерживающем последний, на данный момент, стандарт.

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение для русских и латинских букв (в том числе цифры и знак подчеркивания, так как использую `\w`)

```js
var text = 'Мама мыла раму, а Рамуил в кино ходил.';
var res = text.replace(/(^|[^\wа-яё])(мама|раму)(?![\wа-яё])/gi,
    function() {
        return arguments[1] + '<a>' + arguments[2] + '</a>';    
    })

console.log(res);
```

Символ перед словом придется захватить, так как js не может просматривать назад, и вернуть его через функцию (переменная `arguments[1]`). Само же захваченное слово находится в `arguments[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот это решение:

```
 ([T,t]ext[f|s|t]?)
```

Comment: проблема в том, что слова тут могут быть абсолютно любые в любых (с точки зрения русского языка) словоформах. text тут просто для примера.