# Поиск слов по словарю в блоках

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу написать некий "антимат".
Есть блоки, в которых находится текст, суть в том, чтобы "пройтись" по этим блокам, проверить текст на наличие "запрещённого слова" и заменить его на что-нибудь.

Подумав, решил не делать какие-то замены в самом слове, а просто обернуть его в `span` и ему выставить, допустим `filter: blur(5px)`.

Вооот..

Соль в чём, в голове реализация такая..
"бэдвордс", цикл по блокам, цикл по "бэдвродс"у + поиск слова в тексте, после нахождения заменяем слово на `<span class="badword">слово</span>`..

Я задам это как вопрос, в котором хочу получить уже готовый код, **но** сам тоже буду пытаться написать.
Хотя нет, даже не так, в общем некий конкурс, по окончанию которого, набравший больше "лайков" ответ получить 500 репы.
**По срокам, до 10.03.19**

В общем, надеюсь что будет интересно и админы не закроют)

Допустим всё выглядит так:

```js
let badword = [
  'Lorem',
  'non',
  'lectus',
  'ligula',
  'nisi'
];
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     Suspendisse non pharetra mauris. Suspendisse a lacinia lacus. Nulla facilisi.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     Suspendisse eu lectus aliquam, porttitor est eleifend, blandit mauris.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     Nunc ut bibendum ligula, eu consequat odio. Praesent fermentum nisi a lobortis rhoncus. Phasellus vel metus eu dolor molestie porta. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема с реализацией? В таком вопросе, мне кажется, сложно будет придумать что-то необычное. Какие критерии победы?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, по реализации, может кто-то более грамотнее соберёт. Что-то необычное не нужно, скрипт должен заменять в определённых блоках - определённые слова из массива (словаря), заменять на тот же текст, только в `<span></span>`. Критериями будут голоса пользователей и "рабочий" код)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 на каком языке должен быть список "бэдвордсов"? (это важно)

Comment: @KrychunIvan, в метках указанно, JS или JQ

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 на каком языке должен быть список "бэдвордсов"? (это важно) (x2); пример список "бэдвордсов" это набор русских ругательств, или их английские аналоги?

Comment: @KrychunIvan, а, вон в каком плане.. Любой, "поиск" должен быть по конкретному слову, естественно чтобы не было такого, что слово "оскорблять" было поделено, ну думаю понятно к чему клоню)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 тогда ещё уточняющий вопрос: цель всё таки система "антимат" или поиск "запрещенного" слова? Сразу поясню, это не буквоедство просто разные задачи и разная сложность. В первом случае я набросаю свои мысли в "коде"(возьму за основу русский т.к. там, по моему мнению алгоритм более общный), ну а во-втором вам уже дали ответ.

Comment: @KrychunIvan, хм.. Для меня "антимат" - это как раз таки поиск "запрещённых" слов и действия с ними: замена, удаление, ну или что-то другое.

Comment: @KrychunIvan мы всё ещё ждём вашего ответа. Хочется вариантов. Или хотя бы шлифовки того, что уже дали. Не кармы ради, а ноосферы для))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну вот например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919286/178988 и скриншот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEb4W.png

Comment: @UModeL, товарищ StrangerintheQ уже реализовал мою мысль о "нечетком" (fuzzy) поиске, хотя я склонен к так называемому сходству(дистанции) [Джаро — Винклера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), во-первых из-за моего знакомства с его применением, и во-вторых из-за более подходящей внутренней идеи коэффициента масштабирования; суть которого в улучшенном "рейтинге" для слов при совпадении префиксов. Имея два параметра на слово можно лучше отъюстировать систему.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если контент блоков `.item` не предполагает вложенных тегов, то:

- не нужен массив;
- код сокращается до минимума;
- проверочные слова добавляются через вертикальная черту `|`;
- вместо целых проверочных слов, могут быть дополнительные условия выбора.

```js
let badword = '(Lorem|non|lectus|ligula|nisi)';
let reg = new RegExp(badword, 'gim');

$('.item').each(function() {
  let text = $(this).text();
  text = text.replace(reg, '<span class="bw">$1</span>');
  $(this).html(text);
});
```

```css
.bw { color: red; -webkit-filter: blur(3px); filter: blur(3px); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Suspendisse non pharetra mauris. Suspendisse a lacinia lacus. Nulla facilisi.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Suspendisse eu lectus aliquam, porttitor est eleifend, blandit mauris.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Nunc ut bibendum ligula, eu consequat odio. Praesent fermentum nisi a lobortis rhoncus. Phasellus vel metus eu dolor molestie porta.
  </div>
</div>
```

Если же допускается какое либо форматирование, тогда нужна чуть более сложная логика:

```js
var badword = 'Lorem|non|lectus|ligula|(про)?тест(им)?|nisi|imgur';
var reg = new RegExp('(^|[^\\wа-яё])(' + badword + ')(?![\\wа-яё])', 'gi');

function fAntiSwear(oElem) {
  [...oElem.contents()].forEach(function(oNode) {
    if (oNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { fAntiSwear($(oNode)); } 
    else if (oNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      $(oNode).replaceWith($(oNode).text().replace(reg, '$1<span class="bw">$2</span>'));
    }
  });
}

fAntiSwear($('.content'));
```

```css
.bw { color: red; -webkit-filter: blur(3px); filter: blur(3px); }
.lectus { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <i>consecteturLorem</i> adipiscing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Suspendisse non pharetra mauris. Suspendisse anon lacinia lacus. Nulla facilisi.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Suspendisse eu <u class="lectus">lectus</u> aliquam, porttitor est eleifend, blandit mauris.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Nunc ut bibendum <b class="lectus">ligula</b>, eu consequat <b class="lectus">odio</b>. Praesent fermentum nisi a lobortis rhoncus. Phasellus vel metus eu <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieLDa.jpg?s=32&g=1"> dolor molestie porta.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Протестим слово тест. Ну что, тестим этот протест против теста?
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561771/265406)

Comment: А если, допустим есть какие-то теги, можно как-то регуляркой обходить их?)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 смотря что. Но, можно всё ;-) Вы уточните условия, добавьте примеры, с чем придётся бороться, а то приходится отталкиваться от того, что есть в задании.

Comment: Ну допустим, банально избегать сами теги, внутри тега уже работать, а не с самим тегом.. Типо есть в словаре будет `image`, чтобы он не заменил `<div style="background-<span class="bw">image</span>"></div>`, ну тип такое)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 также, иногда формулируя и дополняя вопрос, приходит понимание, что можно обойтись более простым решением, ибо всё не предусмотришь, а "портянка" кода на две страницы уже))

Comment: Кстати, проверил тут, что и с вариантом от [Misha Saidov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953084/221218), есть недочёт: если ввести в "словарь" слово "б\*\*ть", то слово "оскорблять" заменяться на вот такое `оскор<span class="bw">б**ть</span>`. И ещё, учитывается ли регистр букв?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 нет такого слова "`б**ть`"!!!!!!!!!! Есть слово "`б**Дь`". Я думал, что хоть мат люди знают...

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 учитывать регистр в данном случае - зло, ибо оскорбление может быть написано намеренно вразнобой - тогда вариантов тысячи будут.

Comment: вы меня немного не поняли)) 1. по поводу слова, скрипт должен учитывать только слова, т.е. `оскорблять` "искаться" не будет. 2. По поводу мата, сейчас часто замечаю, что используются оба примера, что вы привели, но не думаю что здесь это можно обсуждать :D 3. Учитывать регистр - да, согласен, зло. Просто уточнил)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 1.порпавил, 2.Подстраиваться под неучей и "олбанский" - плохая практика, ибо они всё равно донесут смысл, обходя все антиматы ;-)

Comment: тут вы правы)) Попрошу поправить код, убрать маты, а то не хотелось бы терять хороший ответ из-за правил, если такие правила есть, конечно же))

Comment: Я изменил, извините, но не удержался))

Comment: Помещать то, что было текстом, в html - плохо. И вообще дыра в безопасности. А уж с jquery ещё более жирная дыра.

Comment: @Qwertiy будьте добры, приведите пример, как в данном случае, воспользоваться этой дырой и мы дополним ответы.

Comment: Для дыры с jQuery достаточно примера из моего ответа. Для нативного js немного посложнее, но похоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy предполагается, что ввод опасных тегов отсекается при вводе, а данный обсуждаемый фильтр используется непосредственно для вывода. Т.е. мы проводим манипуляции с заведомо корректным кодом. Что не так?

Comment: @UModeL, так код-то был корректным до применения фильтра. Отсекать что-то при вводе - это зло. Надо выводить так, чтобы при вводе отсекать не приходилось.

Comment: @Qwertiy категорически не согласен. Я был модератором на одном портале, и там логика не позволяла вводить что-либо, кроме оформления, дабы не запустить непотребство автоматом. А как раз мат пропускала, звездила его при выводе и, при этом, оповещала меня, что в одной из веток начался бадак. Был всегда исходник месседжа - основа для бана. Но попытки ввести неодобренные теги рубились строго при вводе.

Comment: Использовать буду на сайте, где информацию ввожу только я, а "антимат" будет работать от клиента и только визуально, плюс будет в том, что "антимат" можно будет отключить, если юзер этого захочет. Насколько я понял, речь о "дыре" заключается в том, что вы думаете, что "антимат" будет использоваться перед созданием "поста" (скажем так), правильно?

Answer (score 6):

Итак, вот мой вариант.

**Как это работает?**

Чтобы найти в элементе и во ВСЕХ его дочерних элементах плохие слова нужно просто натравить функцию `findBadWords()` на нужный нам элемент. На вход 2 параметра: сам `jq`-элемент (например, `body`) и словарь (массив строк). Например `findBadWords($("body"), ["дурак", "дебил", "пипец"]);`.

Код рекурсивно проходится по всем `textNode` и если находит в них что-то из словаря, то оборачивает это слово в `span` и заменяет предыдущую строку этой новой.

*(!!!) Код нуждается в доработках и в идеале должен быть переписан на ванильный `js` для производительности.*

```js
const findBadWords = (el, dictionary) => {
  let contents = Array.from(el.contents()); // находим всех детей элемента, в том числе и текстовых
  contents.forEach(item => { // проверяем каждого ребенка 
    if (item.nodeType === 1) { // если это не текст то..
      findBadWords($(item), dictionary); // проверяем дальше его детей
    }
    else if (item.nodeType === 3) { // если это просто текст то..
      let regexp = new RegExp(dictionary.join("|"), "gim"); // формируем регулярку из нашего словаря
      $(item).replaceWith(item.textContent.replace(regexp, m => `<span class="badword">${m}</span>`)); // заменяем найденный элемент нашим обработанным текстом
    }
  });
}

$("#start").one("click", () => {
  findBadWords($("#root"), ["дурак", "дебил", "лошара", "пипец"]);
});
```

```css
.badword {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div>
    Дурак - плохое слово.
    <br>
    <span>Дебил лучше тоже не говорить</span>
    <br>
    <button>Кнопка со словом пипец</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            Очень глубоко расположенный лошара
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br><br>
<button id="start">НАЖМИ ЧТОБЫ НАЙТИ ПЛОХИЕ СЛОВА</button>
```

Как видите, коду не важно, где и как глубоко находится плохое слово. Если есть какие-то недочеты или предложения по улучшению - пишите в комментариях.

Comment: К сожалению, не будет работать, если в тексте есть вот такое `<b>ло</b>шара`. Также, будет проблема если в списке плохих слов будут спецсимволы регекспа (скобки, точки и т.д.)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko со вторым согласен, но можно договориться, что словарем будет не массив строк, а массив регекспов, (либо экранировать автоматически символы, если хочется все же строки), но раз мы ищем слова, то спецсимволов быть не должно. А на счёт первого тут сложнее. А что если буква л будет обернута в див с большими отступами и расположена от остальной части слова так, что визуально будет сложно понять, что это это вообще одно такое слово. Вариантов масса, тут лучше не стремиться к идеалу, а работать с голым текстом, к тому же, автор вопроса о таком кейсе ничего не говорил.

Comment: Хорошо бы отобразить в ответе, какие подводные камни и ограничения имеет Ваше решение. И еще неплохо бы использовать `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` и `Node.TEXT_NODE` вместо магических чисел)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko "если в тексте есть вот такое" - с одной строны правильно... Но, это может также просто опечаткой при оформлении. Поэтому, как я уже говорил, не стоит пытаться учесть все возможные варианты - я однажды столкнулся с проблемой, что боролся с антиматом около получаса, пока смог перефразировать так, чтобы не "зазвездило" кучу слов, вполне себе корректных и без малейшего намёка на ругательство.

Answer (score 4):

Мой ответ не сильно отличается оригинальностью в плане взаимодействия с DOM, однако я решил обойтись без внешних библиотек.

Я предлагаю чуть более **умную** реализацию поиска.

Улучшит это поиск или ухудшит это еще вопрос, тут нужны тонкие настройки.

Для поиска **плохих** слов тут используется анализ [**Расстояния Левенштейна**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0).

**Расстояние Левенштейна** между словами **A** и **B** - если коротко, это колчиество символов которое нужно изменить в слове **A** чтобы получить слово **B**.

Это дает возможность найти **похожие** слова.

Я не стал приводить тут наивную рекурсивную реализацию этого алгоритма, с ней можно ознакомится по [этой ссылке](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance).

Для обеспечения работы в словаре откидываются окончания, затем ищутся все элементы, в которых есть слова, **расстояние Левенштейна** до которых меньше или равно **2**(можно слегка улучшить поиск, установив каждому слову свое **пороговое расстояние**) и далее уже следует замена в DOM.

PS. регулярку для выгребания пунктуации тоже нужно усовершенствовать по месту применения.

```js
let minDistance = 2;

let badword = [
  'Lore',
  'non',
  'lectu',
  'ligula',
  'nisi'
];

check(document.querySelector('.content'));

function check(el) {
  if (el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
     markBadwords(el);
  } else {
    [...el.childNodes].forEach(check);
  }
}

function markBadwords(el) {

  let found = el.textContent.split(/,?\s+/).filter(word => {
    return minDistance >= Math.min.apply(null, badword.map(bad => {
      return distance(bad, word.toLowerCase());
    }));
  });
  
  if (!found.length)
    return;
  
  let element = document.createElement('span');
  let regex = new RegExp(found.join("|"), "gim");
  element.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace(regex, w => `<span class="bad">${w}</span>`);
  el.replaceWith(element);

}

// https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance
function distance(a, b) {
  if (a.length === 0) return b.length; 
  if (b.length === 0) return a.length;

  var matrix = [];

  // increment along the first column of each row
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i <= b.length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [i];
  }

  // increment each column in the first row
  var j;
  for (j = 0; j <= a.length; j++) {
    matrix[0][j] = j;
  }

  // Fill in the rest of the matrix
  for (i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
      if (b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)) {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1];
      } else {
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1, // substitution
                                Math.min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1, // insertion
                                         matrix[i-1][j] + 1)); // deletion
      }
    }
  }

  return matrix[b.length][a.length];
};
```

```css
.bad {
  filter: blur(3px)
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
  <div>
     Suspendisse non pharetra mauris. Suspendisse a lacinia lacus. Nulla facilisi.
  </div>
  <div>
     Suspendisse eu lectus aliquam, porttitor est eleifend, blandit mauris.
     <button>
        Suspendisse eu lectus aliquam, porttitor est eleifend, blandit mauris.
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
     Nunc ut bibendum ligul, eu consequat odio. Praesent fermentum nisi a lobortis rhoncus. Phasellus vel metus eu dolor molestie porta. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Разве уместно тут применять расстояние Левенштейна, т.к. может замыливаться большАя часть нормальных слов. По типу "б**дь" есть в запрещённых словах, тогда слово "глянь" тоже замылит, ведь его редакционное расстояние равно 2 :c

Comment: @Kamushek все верно, любой алгоритм либо найдет лишнее либо не найдет нужное, я в конце написал, про то что для разных слов можно указать разное расстояние, а вообще это сильно контекстно зависимая настройка, в конце концов можно 0 поставить для некоторых слов.

Answer (score 3):

Если созданные ранее элементы можно пересоздать, то можно сделать очень просто:

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".content");
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/(^|.)(Lorem|non|lectus|ligula|nisi)(.|$)/gi, (m, l, w, r) => l.toLowerCase() === l.toUpperCase() && r.toLowerCase() === r.toUpperCase() ? `${l}<span class="blur">${w}</span>${r}` : m)
```

```css
.blur {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     Suspendisse non pharetra mauris. Suspendisse a lacinia lacus. Nulla facilisi.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     Suspendisse eu lectus aliquam, porttitor est eleifend, blandit mauris.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     Nunc ut bibendum ligula, eu consequat odio. Praesent fermentum nisi a lobortis rhoncus. Phasellus vel metus eu dolor molestie porta. 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    &lt;script&gt;alert('non');alert('nonconforming');&lt;/script&gt;
  </div>
</div>
```

Если же элементы пересоздавать нельзя, то стоит воспользоваться чем-то таким: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919286/178988

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант)