# Создание текстового поля с автодополнением (autocomplete)

Tags: java, javafx, swing, текст

Уважаемые форумчане! Прошу помощи, полистал уже немало и может не так ищу, может у этого есть другое название.
 Задача такая: есть строка допустим textfield хочу чтобы при вводе туда символов были варианты примерно как поисковая система в гугле, суть такая же, только вариантов сильно меньше. При вводе чтобы выплывал список с подходящими вариантами и можно было на него кликнуть. Интересуют решения на swing и на javafx тоже. Увидеть какой-то пример с мм выбором например из двух слов было бы счастьем.

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решён не могу в комментариях поставить резолвед . Это то что мне нужно.

Comment: Оформил как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется autocomplete,  для Java swing вы можете как найти готовые решения - [библиотеки](https://github.com/fmmfonseca/completely), так и решения на коленке, вроде [этого](http://gist.github.com/resarahadian/5014883)

Или построить свое решение на основе JComboBox, например. Суть примерно всегда одна - по каждому изменению значения в поле - вы перестраиваете модель данных, производя поиск, или какая там у Вас логика для формирования автоподстановки.

Присмотритесь к [расстоянию Левенштейна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953808/188366), простенький алгоритм, позволяет мало-мальски учесть опечатки