# Какие библиотеки на Java существуют для реализации сравнения текста?

Tags: java

Нужно сравнить две версии одного и того же текста. найти отличия в словах, в строке и показать пользователю.
Нашел библиотеку для реализации алгоритма расстояния [Левенштейна](https://github.com/jdereg/java-util). 
Но хочу протестировать и выбрать из алгоритмов лучший и быстрый.

Подскажите пожалуйста ссылки на библиотеки Java для реализации алгоритмов:

- [BK-деревья](https://moluch.ru/archive/52/6873/) ([информация на английском](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree))
- [хэширования по
  сигнатуре](https://moluch.ru/archive/52/6873/)
- [метод N-грамм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)
- метод последовательного перебора
- [алгоритмы шинглов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [метод расширенного выбора](https://habr.com/ru/post/341148/)

Comment: А чем тебе мешает самому написать код? Вроде библиотек для таких целей нету. Даже на питоне не помню есть ли они. На Джаве таких явно нету.

Comment: Какая цель сравнения? Из описания похоже на функционал сравнения версий файлов из IDE или гуи для git/svn. Если так, то само по себе расстояние Левенштейна вам так себе помощник, как и построенное на его основе ВК-дерево. Шинглы, в теории, могут быть полезны, но мне кажется он будет не самым удобным для вашей задачи. Могу предложить поискать готовое решение в опенсорной IDE, например, в Intellij IDEA. Там есть функционал сравнения версий файла при работе с CVS

Comment: Ну а по действиям - как по мне реализовать несложный алгоритм поиска совпадающих подстрок на основе таблицы, построенной при поиске редакционного расстояния, будет эффективнее по времени чем искать готовое решение =)

Comment: @Спицко Дмитрий - мне для сравнения текста двух текстовых файлов. Сплошной текст. Это не исходники. Библиотеки есть, нашел для алгоритма Левенштейна. Вот думаю может и для други алгоритмов есть.

Comment: @Спицко Дмитрий а для сравнения текста (два файла Word с текстом.) какие алгоритмы из указанных и других пойдут? и почему?
Нужно сравнить слова и /или строки и показать отличия. 

Орфографию проверять, ошибки проверять, пунктуацию проверять НЕ нужно.

Comment: Ну, давайте по порядку попробуем. ВК-дерево - точно нет. Это дерево хорошо для поиска в бд по ключевым словам, если мы допускаем ошибки при вводе, но для выяснения общих/различных элементов текста я с трудом представляю себе как его использовать

Comment: хэш по маске опять таки сомнительное удовольствие. Для анализа текста может пригодится, но для разметки различных элементов - тяжело, имхо. Опять таки, для поиска по ключевым словам самое то, именно для такой задачи я его использую

Comment: алгоритм шинглов схож с хэшем по маске, только хэшит не слова, а  фразы. Рациональное использование - когда искомый текст значительно короче поля поиска. Тоже не то...

Comment: С остальными методами не знаком. Я бы предложил анализировать таблицу, получаемую при построении расстояния Левенштейна. Строите таблицу сравнивая предложения или абзацы(чем длиннее строки, тем хуже, сложность от n2). Если в таблице по диагонали повторяются числа - значит эти части строк совпадают. Так легко выделять совпадающие элементы. Из глобального нужно еще порядок предложений учесть, если в одном документе идут предложения АВ, а во втором АСВ, то надо как-то заставить алгоритм сравнивать 2 предложение одного документа и 3 другого. Мне кажется для вашей задачи такого подхода за глаза

Comment: @Спицко Дмитрий спасибо большое. Ещё одно уточнение, правильно понял что для сравнения с использованием метода Левенштейна не требуется создавать словарь с заранее подготовленным перечнем слов. Тогда как вк-дерево, хэширования по сигнатура, нужны ещё и словари реализовывать? Так? А для других указанных методов нужны словари им?

Comment: @Спицко Дмитрий вы писали "хэш по маске опять таки сомнительное удовольствие. Для анализа текста может пригодится, но для разметки различных элементов - тяжело, " . А что значит "для разметки различных элементов"? Можете пример привести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расстояние Левенштейна, оно же редакционное - это функция от двух слов/текстов, возвращающая количество замен и вставок букв, чтобы получить из одного другое. Само по себе расстояние вам не поможет, а вот таблица, которая строится для его вычисления - может, но об этом чуть позже. Ну и словарь создавать нет смысла. Вы проверяете кусок текста из одного документа с куском текста из другого, расстояние 0 - совпали полностью.

bk- дерево - это словарь. Строится такое дерево на основе расстояния Левенштейна. В корне лежит пустое слово. Его узлы - все слова из словаря, которые имеют расстояние до пустого слова 1, то есть слова в одну букву. У них в ветках все слова, от которых до них расстояние один. Это если сильно упрощать, но суть в том, что вы берете некоторый исходный набор данных, который не меняется, и упрощаете себе поиск слов в этом наборе данных. Например, поиск по базе организаций 2Гис. Там строят такое дерево и очень быстро определяют какие слова вы вводите и на какие объекты они должны вас ссылать. То есть есть некоторый набор данных, который не меняется, и вы в нем ищете меньший объем данных. Это не ваш случай

Тоже самое можно сказать о хэше по сигнатуре и шинглах. Они заключаются в первичной обработке константных данных, внутри которых надо быстро искать более мелкие данные. Опять таки, не ваш случай, если у вас два сравнимых по объему и каждый раз новых текста.

С другими представленными вами алгоритмами я не знаком, к сожалению.

Вернемся к редакционному расстоянию. Когда его считают для двух строк с длинами M и N, строится таблица размена M+1 на N+1. В Вики есть описание этой таблицы. Так вот, если в ней по диагонали идут одинаковые числа - значит на этом участке строки возможно(!) совпадают. Так можно довольно быстро искать общие элементы у небольших объемов текста. Я бы рекомендовал подумать именно в этом направлении, для начала

Ну а по повод готовых решений - как вариант посмотреть опенсорсные IDE или GUI для систем контроля версий. В них обязательно имеются инструменты, показывающие различия фалов, то есть примерно то, что вам нужно. Но, кажется мне, найти в большом проекте нужную вам часть будет ой как не быстро, проще самому написать =)

Comment: Ааа, приложение бесит) доберусь до компа поправлю и доотвечаю

Comment: А какие вы библиотеки java используете? Для расстояния Левенштейна,  бк-дерева, алгоритм шинглов, хэш по маске?

Comment: Расстояние левенштейна - ."....Само по себе расстояние вам не поможет, а вот таблица, которая строится для его вычисления".   А что, результаты сравнения можно вывести в виде таблицы? Можете показать пример?

Comment: И последний вопрос, как называется алгоритм сравнения значений двух полей разных версий карточки документа? Там же искать наверное и сопоставлять не нужно? Просто показать изменение? Карточка документа - это формочка с отображением атрибутов документа: наименование, обозначение, версия, дата создания.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Библиотек я не использовал, когда работал с этими алгоритмами, потому что подобные задачи всегда имеют свои специфики, и универсальных алгоритмов не существует. Например, я изрядно так поиздевался над редакционным расстоянием, чтобы оно давало более актуальный для моей задачи результат. А про карточки документов не совсем понял. Это часть вашего интерфейса?

Comment: @Kirumit как то раз использовал расстояние господина Левенштейна для ответа на вопрос, там есть код для подсчета расстояния... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953808/188366

Comment: @Спицко Дмитрий - карточка документа, это часть интерфейса. Нужно сравнить значения полей двух форм "карточка документа" ну или по другому - нужно сравнить две записи в таблице и отобразить результат чем отличается (проверять ошибки не нужно, только сравнить). В этом случае тоже какой то алгоритм нужен, типа Левенштейна? Или значения полей по другому сравниваются?