# Как найти и заменить слово в тексте с сохранением стилей?

Tags: javascript

Есть поле с текстом, на который накинуты css стили

Допустим, у меня есть следующий текст:

```
...at anyone who did not dress...
```

, где мне нужно найти и заменить "did not" на "did't"
Задача проста, пока у текста не появляются стили и он становится следующим:

```
...at anyone who <span style='color: #ff0000;'>did</span> not dress...
```

Если я просто сделаю `obj.innerText.replace("did not", "did't")`, то стиль не сохранится, а `obj.innerHtml.replace("did not", "did't")` не найдет

Есть ли элегантное решение?

UDP: имеется позиция в тексте начала и конца фразы/слова, а так же индекс в случае повторения

Comment: А как тогда это слово должно будет заменятся? <span style='color: #ff0000;'>did</span>'nt что-ли?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan Нет, полностью слово в стиль обернуть

Comment: @grvctr: будьте добры, приведите ещё пару примеров замены.

Comment: @UModeL в плане просто слов или вариантов со стилями?

Comment: @grvctr: в плане - не только "did not", а и другие слова. Ну и стили, если отличаются. Короче, чтобы по типу "было-стало".

Comment: @grvctr: гляньте - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953084/265406 Может натолкнёт Вас на мысль.

Comment: @UModeL
Her -> their
were not -> weren't;
recently <span style='color: #ff0000;'>purchased</span> -> recently <span style='color: #ff0000;'>bought</span>;
<span style="font-size: 20px">H</span>er -> Their (в таких случаях строгости нет, либо с сохранением, либо полностью оборачивать);

Comment: @grvctr: а кто "накидывает" изначальные inline-стили? Тоже ваш скрипт? Если да, то самое простое решение: брать `innerText`-ом, делать замену слов и заново "накидывать".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112269/discussion-between-grvctr-and-umodel).

Comment: @UModeL, нет, это делает пользователь. Суть приложения обработка текста. Аналог Grammarly