# регулярные выражения: выделения русских и английских слов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск

Требуется выделять из текста русские и английские слова

Написал такую регулярярку:

```
\b([\w'а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)\b
```

Она выделяет английские слова, но русские игнорирует.
Так же выделяюется английские слова внутри которых есть русские буквы.
Вроде как дело в \b (ограничение слова), но как быть без нее?

Подскажите как корректнее модифицировать данное ругулярное выражение?

Comment: Еще бывает так, что регулярка не реагирует на а-яА-ЯёЁ, тогда попробуйте явно перечислить каждую букву алфавита вместо диапазона

Answer (score 1):

В последних версиях движков добавили гибкости регуляркам:

```js
const rExp = /(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])[a-z'а-яё]+(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])/gui;

const sTxt = 'Требуется select из текста русские & english words';

console.log(sTxt.match(rExp))
```

Решение взято [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1514436/265406).